# Считывание с клавиатуры в Windows Forms С++

Tags: c++, winforms

Как считать символ введенный с клавиатуры в Windows Forms С++(без из пользования консоли)?

Задача состоит в том, что при клике на Button, а затем нажатии на рандомную клавишу(допустим s), на Button появлялся символ с этой клавиши(s).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4  либа UiPath Robot если надо прост измените названия